Не удаётся корректно прочитать файл .xlsx с помощью pandas, python. Все значения NaN
Всем привет. Проблема с чтением файла .xlsx с помощью модуля pandas в python. Все значения отображаются как NaN. Openpyxl импортирован.
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('../data/test.xlsx')

data = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['FIO', 'MIO'])

print(data)




Так в вашем .xlsx нет колонок FIO и MIO - где данные то брать?

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Amgarak\Desktop\13.xlsx')  
# data = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['FIO', 'MIO'])
data = df[['FIO', 'MIO']]

print(df, end="\n\n")
print(data)

df - уже DataFrame, так можно сразу с ним работать -> df[['FIO', 'MIO']]
Вывод:
       FIO  TG      MIO
0   Петров   9    67678
1  Сидоров  10   567678
2   Иванов  11  4565767

       FIO      MIO
0   Петров    67678
1  Сидоров   567678
2   Иванов  4565767

